# My engine stalled and wont restart - after downshifting - Automatic Trans

Tags: engine, starting, chrysler, stall, town-and-country

My engine stalled and wont restart - All I did was downshift...

2005 Chrysler Town & Country Limited.  V6 - 3.8 Liter EFI.

For some history, a couple days ago I noticed a clicking sound - it sounded like a playing card in spokes - or a helicopter sound... It intensified as I accelerated.  Not sure what that was or whether it is related to what happened today...

Today I had to use the car to drop kids off at school.  On my way home, it pained me to accelerate because I was concerned that I was harming the engine.  When slowing down, I shifted from "D" to "L" (at around 15 PMH), and the engine just stopped.  The engine won't start at all.  battery is good, won't even turn over.  One strange thing, the power windows won't work, but the power sliding doors open and close fine.  Could I have blown a fuse causing the engine to stop immediately, and then to not start?  Is this a failsafe engineered into the car?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the headlights turn on?  When you turn the key to 'on' does the radio and light on the dash come on?  I am assuming the sliding door is 'full time power.'  Windows are typically 'on power.'  Might be an issue with a loose connection at the ignition switch or a bad switch.  Could also be a bad ground / battery connection.  Blown fuse is still a possibility.  Only way to really tell is to get a schematic and poke at it with a test light.

Comment: Have you tried jiggling the key in the ignition switch to see if you can establish contact?  In some cases the ignition switch being faulty can create the symptoms you are experiencing.  This is admittedly a reach yet still a possibility.  rpmerf has salient points in his comments.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?